# Extracting text from column and making it lowercase and exists in array

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I want to extract text from a column in my df where the df has column text like:

df:

```
    text
    @bobby
    @mike
    why @mike
    huh, @brad
    @brad
    cmon @Sunny_Bat
    @Sunny_Bat
    @But_ten
    @g2
    @Mikey/fj
    @4242343
```

I have code that gives me the extracted text or word after @ like below:

```
df['text'].str.extract(r"@([A-Za-z_]+([0-9]+)*)")[0]
```

This gives me the output I want by extracting the word if it exists but is not a number as the expected output below:

```
Desired Output:

text        | new column
@bobby          bobby
@mike           mike
why @mike       mike
huh, @brad      brad
@brad           brad 
cmon @Sunny_bat Sunny_bat
@Sunny_Bat      Sunny_bat
@But_ten        But_ten
@g2             g2
@Mikey/fj       Mikey
@4242343        NaN
```

But what I am missing is I want my new column to have values that exist in another column in the same df or an array of unique values of that column called unique_values like below:

```
isin(unique_values))
```

I am trying to add via something like:

`where(lambda x: x[0].isin(name_list))`

but not sure how to add to my above code

Also,

Where I can add the isin to the end of the code above to output only values or words that exist in this array, also I want the outputted words to all be lowercase only since the words in unique values are lowercase but in the text column that is being extracted are not lower case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change regex for remove second pair `()` and `*` for optional integers, add `expand=False` for `Series`, convert to lowercase for match list in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) chain `|` for bitwise `Or` for test missing values with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabe/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['new'] = df['text'].str.extract(r"@([A-Za-z_]+[0-9]*)", expand=False).str.lower()
print (df)
                   text        new
0                @bobby      bobby
1                 @mike       mike
2             why @mike       mike
3            huh, @brad       brad
4                 @brad       brad
5       cmon @Sunny_Bat  sunny_bat
6            @Sunny_Bat  sunny_bat
7              @But_ten    but_ten
8                   @g2         g2
9             @Mikey/fj      mikey
10             @4242343        NaN

unique_values = ['sunny_bat','brad','bobby']

df = df[df['new'].isin(unique_values) | df['new'].isna()]
print (df)
                   text        new
0                @bobby      bobby
3            huh, @brad       brad
4                 @brad       brad
5       cmon @Sunny_Bat  sunny_bat
6            @Sunny_Bat  sunny_bat
10             @4242343        NaN
```

Comment: Hi, @jezrael  - But how Can I add to this code if this is  - isin my array values of unique_values?

Comment: @Chris90 - Answer was edited, also is added `str.lower()` for lowercase values after extract.

Comment: @Chris90 - Some problem?

Comment: Hi, Just one more question! 

it works thanks, when I filter after,  it works that way too, but I forgot to mention I also have nulls or NaN in my df['new'] column, how can I filter for unique value but also keep all NaNs as well?

Comment: I want to filter where the values in my new column exist in unique values array but also can be NaN or keep the Nans if that make sense thanks!

Comment: offtopic question - I get error on a simple code line like this

df.name = df.name.astype(str).str.lower()

gives me error of - A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

any idea why maybe? @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - It is good question need `df = df[df['new'].isin(unique_values) | df['new'].isna()].copy()` - if you modify values in df later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (df), and that Pandas does warning.